# Python Pandas Date time: Adding a new column to dataframe based on date time index dynamic conditions

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, datetime, conditional-statements

I want to add a new column to pandas data frame df based on the time index conditions.
the "years_list" can vary and could be more than 3 years. The **objective** is to add a new column with the value 1 in each of the periods of times defined by "start_date" and "end_date".

My **question** is there any way to automatically consider the 3 periods at the same time?

Using the numpy select method seems not to be thee ideal solution because I would have to define the conditions manually for each year. However the desire is to have an automatic way because "years_list" is dynamic.

I typed the following code but it's not the right solution because the new column and the df do not habe the same length:

```
new_col= []
years_list= [2020,2021,2023]

for year in years_list:
  start_date= pd.to_datetime(str(year)+'-03-01 00:00:00')
  end_date  = pd.to_datetime(str(year)+'-03-07 00:00:00')

for idx in range(len(df)):

   if df.index[idx] => start_date and df.index[idx] <= end_date:
         new_col.append(1)
   else:
         new_col.append(2)

df["newC"] = new_col
```

Result:

| date time (index) | new col |
| --- | --- |
| 2020-01-01 00:00:00 | 2 |
| ... | 2 |
| 2020-02-29 00:00:00 | 2 |
| **2020-03-01 00:00:00** | 1 |
| **2020-03-02 00:00:00** | 1 |
| ... | 1 |
| **2020-03-07 00:00:00** | 1 |
| 2020-03-08 00:00:00 | 2 |
| 2020-03-31 00:00:00 | 2 |
| ... | 2 |
| 2021-01-01 00:00:00 | 2 |
| ... | 2 |
| 2021-02-28 00:00:00 | 2 |
| **2021-03-01 00:00:00'** | 1 |
| **2021-03-02 00:00:00'** | 1 |
| ... | 1 |
| **2021-03-07 00:00:00** | 1 |
| 2021-03-08 00:00:00 | 2 |
| 2021-03-31 00:00:00 | 2 |
| ... | 2 |
| 2022-01-31 00:00:00 | 2 |
| ... | 2 |
| 2022-12-31 00:00:00 | 2 |
| 2023-01-01 00:00:00 | 2 |
| ... | 2 |
| 2023-02-28 00:00:00 | 2 |
| **2023-03-01 00:00:00** | 1 |
| **2023-03-02 00:00:00** | 1 |
| ... | 1 |
| **2023-03-07 00:00:00** | 1 |
| 2023-03-08 00:00:00 | 2 |

Comment: please add the expected result. please refer to the guidelines in providing a reproducible example https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: start_date and end_date will hold value from the last iteration

Comment: this the point, I don't know how to consider the three period of time conditions at the same time

Comment: @Naveed I just added an example of the expected result

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To create a Dataframe with a list of year (your code modified here)

```
new_col= []
years_list= [2020,2021,2023]
start_date = []
end_date = []

for year in years_list:
  start_date.append(pd.to_datetime(str(year)+'-03-01 00:00:00'))
  end_date.append(pd.to_datetime(str(year)+'-03-07 00:00:00'))
    
start_date
df = pd.DataFrame({'start': start_date, 'end': end_date})    
df
```

```
start   end
0   2020-03-01  2020-03-07
1   2021-03-01  2021-03-07
2   2023-03-01  2023-03-07
```

Sample dataframe to choose dates that exists in above DF

```
# data,df2=read_cb()
data ={'data': {0: 0, 1: 1, 2: 2, 3: 3, 4: 4, 5: 5, 6: 6, 7: 7, 8: 8},
 'date': {0: '03/01/2020',  1: '03/02/2020',  2: '03/10/2020',  3: '03/01/2021',  4: '03/01/2021',  5: '03/11/2021',  6: '03/01/2023',  7: '03/01/2023',  8: '03/21/2023'},
 'saldo': {0: 310.36,  1: 312.86,  2: 315.34,  3: 317.84,  4: 326.44,  5: 224.44,  6: 317.84,  7: 326.44,  8: 224.44}}
df=pd.DataFrame(data)
df
```

```
    data    date    saldo
0   0   03/01/2020  310.36
1   1   03/02/2020  312.86
2   2   03/10/2020  315.34
3   3   03/01/2021  317.84
4   4   03/01/2021  326.44
5   5   03/11/2021  224.44
6   6   03/01/2023  317.84
7   7   03/01/2023  326.44
8   8   03/21/2023  224.44
```

Using pandasql to do a join

```
from pandasql import sqldf
pysqldf = lambda q: sqldf(q, globals())


qry = """
select *
from df2
  left join df
on df2.date between df.start and df.end
"""
pysqldf = lambda q: sqldf(q, globals())
result=pysqldf(qry)
result
```

```
data    date    saldo   start   end
0   0   2020-03-01 00:00:00.000000  310.36  2020-03-01 00:00:00.000000  2020-03-07 00:00:00.000000
1   1   2020-03-02 00:00:00.000000  312.86  2020-03-01 00:00:00.000000  2020-03-07 00:00:00.000000
2   2   2020-03-10 00:00:00.000000  315.34  None    None
3   3   2021-03-01 00:00:00.000000  317.84  2021-03-01 00:00:00.000000  2021-03-07 00:00:00.000000
4   4   2021-03-01 00:00:00.000000  326.44  2021-03-01 00:00:00.000000  2021-03-07 00:00:00.000000
5   5   2021-03-11 00:00:00.000000  224.44  None    None
6   6   2023-03-01 00:00:00.000000  317.84  2023-03-01 00:00:00.000000  2023-03-07 00:00:00.000000
7   7   2023-03-01 00:00:00.000000  326.44  2023-03-01 00:00:00.000000  2023-03-07 00:00:00.000000
8   8   2023-03-21 00:00:00.000000  224.44  None    None
```